# Recovering a saved email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, backup

A person with low computer skills was writing a message in Gmail (web interface). You know how as you type it automatically saves the message and the word "saved" appears at the bottom, she clicked "saved" thinking it was the command to save. Now she can't find her message.

Is there any way of getting it back?

Comment: Did you check drafts? When i clicked saved nothing happened. It didn't close the window.

Comment: Checked drafts.

Answer (score 1):

The saved label is not click-able, usually to find your message go to drafts definitely you will find it there, i just checked it, even if you had closed the browser and if you then saw saved notification that means that the message already has been saved to Drafts, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that the message isn't in her Drafts folder and she saw the "saved" notification - that might suggest the message is in her Deleted folder.

When replying/forwarding a message in the **Deleted folder**, a draft is saved, but isn't shown in Draft folder. You need to find the original message, open it, there you'll see the draft.